# Is there a resize event for screen in Windows

Tags: winapi

I have a simple app that changes numlock state when I'm connected to a docking station. The problem is I don't know how to detect when a second monitor is connected (and disconnected) so that I only set the state once it is connected. So I'm looking for Screen.Resize event or similar.

I'm working on Windows 7 so I will settle for Windows 7 only solution though I'd like a more universal solution if possible.

Another thing - this should be a VS 2008 C++ Express compatible solution ;-), but I have access to full VS at work so MFC requirement would be manageable too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Cool. This does seem to work even when returning form hibernation.

The app is here:
http://enux.pl/download/onresize/OnResizeSwitch.zip
Note that you would probably have to fine tune this for your needs. Solution will work with VS C++ 2008 Express.